# How to install ADFS 3.0 in standalone mode?

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I've installed Windows 2012 R2 and enabled the ADFS (3.0?) feature. After installation, it asks to configure ADFS, but this step requires a user account that is a domain administrator, as it wants to create certificate containers and SPN records.

In ADFS 2.0, you could install in standalone mode which required only local admin rights, storing everything in the Windows Internal Database.

If this still possible in the latest version to install locally without domain admin privileges? If so, how do I configure ADFS in standalone mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option for standalone installs has been removed. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831502.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I searched but did not find that article. So what's the recommended approach for development environments? Everyone create their own domain? Seems like a lot of hassle to work around something ADFS supported in the past. Any idea why this was discontinued?

Comment: Updating previous comment. Standalone installs cannot be converted to farm mode. Customers that deploy in standalone mode when they want to convert to a farm mode cant do so. Which means a re-build.